# ReactJS pass props to child via redux ajax

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I have a reactjs component with redux which passes asynchronously props to child component.

In child component I try to catch the data in componentDidMount but somehow does not work either, however the child component is getting rendered.

This is my parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as slidesActions from '../../actions/slidesActions';
import Slider from '../Partials/Slider'
import _ from 'underscore';


class HomePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.getSlides()
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {slides} = this.props;
    }

    render() {
        const {slides} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="homePage">
                <Slider columns={1}  slides={slides} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        slides: state.slides
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(slidesActions, dispatch)
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

here comes my child component where I try to get passed slides props but is empty

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'underscore';
import Hammer from 'hammerjs';


class Slider extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.updatePosition = this.updatePosition.bind(this);
        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
        this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            images: [],
            slidesLength: null,
            currentPosition: 0,
            slideTransform: 0,
            interval: null
        };
    }

    next() {
        const currentPosition = this.updatePosition(this.state.currentPosition - 10);
        this.setState({ currentPosition });

    }

    prev() {
        //TODO: work on logic
        if( this.state.currentPosition !== 0) {
            const currentPosition = this.updatePosition(this.state.currentPosition + 10);
            this.setState({currentPosition});
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        //here I try set a state variable on slides 
        let {slides} = this.props
        let slidesLength = slides.length 
        this.setState({slidesLength})

        this.hammer = Hammer(this._slider)
        this.hammer.on('swipeleft', this.next);
        this.hammer.on('swiperight', this.prev);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.hammer.off('swipeleft', this.next)
        this.hammer.off('swiperight', this.prev)
    }

    updatePosition(nextPosition) {
        const { visibleItems, currentPosition } = this.state;
        return nextPosition;
    }

    render() {
        let {slides, columns} = this.props
        let {currentPosition} = this.state
        let sliderNavigation = null

        //TODO: this should go to slides actions
        let slider = _.map(slides, function (slide) {
            let Background = slide.featured_image_url.full;
            if(slide.status === 'publish')
                return <div className="slide" id={slide.id}  key={slide.id}><div className="Img" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Background})` }} data-src={slide.featured_image_url.full}></div></div>
        });

        if(slides.length > 1 ) {

          sliderNavigation =   <ul className="slider__navigation">
                <li data-slide="prev" className="" onClick={this.prev}>previous</li>
                <li data-slide="next" className="" onClick={this.next}>next</li>
            </ul>
        }

        return <div ref={
            (el) => this._slider = el
        } className="slider-attached"
                    data-navigation="true"
                    data-columns={columns}
                    data-dimensions="auto"
                    data-slides={slides.length}>
                    <div className="slides" style={{ transform: `translate(${currentPosition}%, 0px)`, left : 0 }}> {slider} </div>

                    {sliderNavigation}
            </div>
    }
}

export default Slider;
```

and here I have my actions for slider

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'underscore';


//TODO: this should be accessed from DataService
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    var slidesEndPoint = 'http://dev.server/wp-json/wp/v2/slides';
} else {
    var slidesEndPoint = 'http://prod.server/wp-json/wp/v2/slides';
}

export function getSlides () {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingState()); // Show a loading spinner

        axios.get(slidesEndPoint)
            .then(function (response) {
                dispatch(setSlides(response.data))
                dispatch(doneFetchingData(response.data))
            })
            /*.error((response) => {
                dispatch(showError(response.data))
            })*/

    }
}


function setSlides(data) {
    return {
        type: types.SLIDES_SUCCESS,
        slides: data
    }
}


function setLoadingState() {
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_SPINNER,
        loaded: false
    }
}

function doneFetchingData(data) {
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_SPINNER,
        loaded: true,
        slides: data
    }
}

function showError() {
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_ERROR,
        loaded: false,
        error: 'error'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, `componentDidMount` will get called only once, just after the initial rendering, since you are fetching the data asynchronously so before you get the data Slider component will get rendered.

So You need to use `componentwillreceiveprops` lifecycle method.

**[componentDidMount:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):**

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Write it like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(nextProps.slides){
         let {slides} = nextProps.props
         let slidesLength = slides.length;        

         this.hammer = Hammer(this._slider)
         this.hammer.on('swipeleft', this.next);
         this.hammer.on('swiperight', this.prev);
         this.setState({slidesLength})
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are doing an `axios` call to fetch the data and then set it in the reducer which you are returning later. Also initially reducer data is empty . Now since `componentDidMount` is called only once, and initially no data may have been there you are not seeing any values. Use a `componentWillReceiveProps` function

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        //here I try set a state variable on slides 
        let {slides} = nextProps
        let slidesLength = slides.length 
        this.setState({slidesLength})

        this.hammer = Hammer(this._slider)
        this.hammer.on('swipeleft', this.next);
        this.hammer.on('swiperight', this.prev);
    }
```